# Error when deploying a REST service via Jersey on a Virtual Machine

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, gradle, build.gradle

I have a simple web service exposing Java resources through REST using Jersey2 and Jetty. It works fine on my laptop's localhost. However, when I deploy the same code onto a virtual machine on my company's network, I get an error. Without Jersey, Jetty runs successfully and the welcome page displays fine on the virtual machine.

I have searched for similar issues and found [**this promising one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265649/jersey2-sample-rest-service-failing), however what worked for *PrasanthNath* doesn't seem to apply to my case. I have tried with version 2.6 of the libraries suggested on that link, too but it didn't make a difference.

I'd highly appreciate your thoughts. Thank you in advance!

Here's the error I get:

```
$ gradle jettyRunWar
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:war UP-TO-DATE
:jettyRunWar
failed Jersey REST Service: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL
failed org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext@248d3e1b{/dgp_ky_140310,/home/unix    /kyuksel/dgp_ky_140310/build/libs/dgp_ky_140310-0.1.war}: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:     INCLUDE_ALL
failed ContextHandlerCollection@7915b3e: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL
failed HandlerCollection@57fd4753: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL

Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$State.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:110)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:351)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:294)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext.doStart(JettyPluginWebAppContext.java:112)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.startJettyInternal(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:238)
at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.startJetty(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:191)
at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.start(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:95)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

This is the snapshot of the **org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig** code where the error (**line 110**) is coming from:

```
109  public More ...State() {
110      super(RuntimeType.SERVER, ComponentBag.INCLUDE_ALL);
111      this.classLoader = AccessController.doPrivileged(ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA());
112 
113      this.resourceFinders = Sets.newHashSet();
114 
115      this.resources = Sets.newHashSet();
116      this.resourcesView = Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.resources);
117  }
```

Here's my **build.gradle** with the dependencies:

```
version = '0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'war'

checkstyle {
    configFile = new File(rootDir, "checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.broadinstitute.genomestore.GenomeStore',
               'Implementation-Title': 'GenomeStore',
               'Implementation-Version': version
}
    from { 
            configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1beta2-rev36-1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev129-1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'javax.json:javax.json-api:1.0'
    compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey:jax-rs-ri:2.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.4'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.4'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-processing:2.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}

task(runGenomeStore, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.broadinstitute.genomestore.GenomeStore'

    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

defaultTasks 'build'
```

Here's my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ResultStoreServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.broadinstitute.genomestore.rest.ResultStoreServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ResultStoreServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<display-name>dgp_ky_140310</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.broadinstitute.genomestore.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And finally here's my sample class:

```
@Path("/server/")
public class Server {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public JsonObject getJson() {
        JsonObject model = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("gene_info", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("DESCRIPTION", "The protein encoded by this gene ...")
                .add("NAME", "XXX")
                .add("SYMBOL", "YYY")
                .add("VARIANT_SUMMARY", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("NEAR_GENE_NOMINAL", "99")
                    .add("OTHER_TRAIT_GENOMEWIDE", "99")                   
                    .add("TOTAL_VARIANTS", "289")))
            .add("is_error", false)
            .build();

        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by removing javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0 changing org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-processing:2.7 to version 2.4. I had done some playing with libraries while developing the code and apparently let build.gradle and library folder get out of sync, which got exposed only when I deployed the code on the virtual machine, which lacked some of the essential libraries.