# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying create a Web Service RESTFUL using Jersey with Maven and Tomcat. When I do execute my webservice, does throws some exceptions and doesn't works.

How could I solve it ?

**URL**

http://localhost:8080/FerpaWS/ws/cliente

**Service**

```
package br.com.ferpa.ws;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/")
public class Cliente {

    @GET
    @Path("/cliente")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getNome(){
       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
       obj.put("nome", "fernando paiva");
       return Response.status(200).entity(obj.toString()).build();
    }    
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <display-name>FerpaWS</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>br.com.ferpa.ws</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**Exception**

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:92)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @peeskittet I have similar problem, but how can I remove dependency on Javaee as you suggest. Any suggestion. thanks

Comment: Check the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265649/jersey2-sample-rest-service-failing) talking about inconsistent dependencies

Answer (score 6):

That error means you are mixing Jersey 1.x and 2.x. Both are totally incompatible, make sure that all your dependencies are of the same version.

```
com.sun.jersey
```

is for Jersey 1.x. It should not be used.

```
org.glassfish.jersey
```

is Jersey 2.x and should be used whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

I see one issue in your code

```
@Path("/") <--- here
public class Cliente {

    @GET
    @Path("/cliente")
```

As per your code, the url to access `getNome` method would be

```
http://localhost:8080/FerpaWS/ws//cliente
```

But, you are accessing

```
 http://localhost:8080/FerpaWS/ws/cliente
```

So, either you removed `@Path("/")` or name something `@Path("/app")`. So, finally url would be

```
http://localhost:8080/FerpaWS/ws/app/cliente
```

Answer (score -1):

add the Maven dependencies in the Deployment Assembly or just clean and build you project.

> just right click on the project

Properties

> Deployment Assembly
>
> Add
>
> It will open other window, in that choose
>
> Java Build Path Entries
>
> click Next