# RESTfull Jersey application, The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

It's my first attempt with RESTfull application. I have read many pages with problem same as mine, but they didn't quiet hit a mark.

This is my service.

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {

   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

   @GET
   @Path("/users")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<User> getUsers(){
      return userDao.getAllUsers();
   }    
}
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>User Management</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Restful Web Service</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

I am using Jersey 2.17 and Tomcat 7.0. It looks like all .jar's are added properly to **/WEB-INF/lib**. I exported my project as .war file and put it into **/Tomcat/webapps** directory.
Then I am trying to launch

> http://localhost:8080/RestV1/rest/UserService

I am getting this error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /RestV1/rest/UserService/users The requested resource is
>   not available.

The methodes are from tutorial so there shouldn't be any problem with them. Also my Tomcat error log is empty.
Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: is RestV1.war the name of the war you produce?

Comment: yes Sir, and the name of the project.

Comment: I think you just need the servlet-name to match in the <servlet> and <servlet-mapping> . I'll test it out and write it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same `<servlet-name>` you define in `<servlet>` in the `<servlet-mapping>`.  So with servlet definition:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
  ...
</servlet>
```

Your mapping should look like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <!-- this will not map properly
     <servlet-name>Restful Web Service</servlet-name>
   -->
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I downloaded Tomcat and made sure I got the 404 when the names didn't match, and the request reached the servelt when they did.

As a reference, search servlet-mappings and note that the names used always match in these [examples](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Did you clear out all the cache in Tomcat? I had to delete the folder that had been exploded by my previous deployment.

Comment: Cache clear didnt help Now I got different error. "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey RESTful Application threw exception", The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: Believe it or not, that's good.  Your servlet is now being registered.  I don't know how you are building the war, but I think you are experiences issues with that.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136257/http-status-500-servlet-init-for-servlet-jersey-serlvet-threw-exception

Comment: Thank Sir, I am finishing my work for today. If I have some questions I ll post them here.

Comment: I solved my "Status 500"  It was due to different Java versions. I was creating it in 1.8 and building in 1.7. In my Eclipse I right clicket on my project selected "properties" -> "Project Facets" and there downgraded the java to 1.7. And It works now.

Comment: Great! Glad you figured it out